# (Python) Check if strings in a column in a dataframe contain words from multiple columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have two tables that look like this:

Table1:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | I love dogs |
| 2 | I love cats |
| 3 | I love dogs and cats |
| 4 | Cats love me |

Table2:

| Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| I | cats |
| me | dogs |

I want to check if texts in the columns of Table1 contains words in the column of Table2. New column will be added to Table2. Column E should show all id numbers of the rows in Table1 that contain the word in Column C of the same row. Column F should show all id numbers of the rows in Table1 that contain the word in both Column C AND Column D of the same row.

Now I'm using for-loops with iterrows() and fnmatch to search through both tables. My code looks something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

table_1_data = {'Column A': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        'Column B': ['I love dogs', 'I love cats', 'I love dogs and cats', 'Cats love me']}
table_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table_1_data )

 
table_2_data = {'Column C': ['I', 'me'],
        'Column D': ['cats', 'dogs']} 
table_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table_2_data )


table_2['Column E'] = ''
table_2['Column F'] = ''

for index, row in table_1.iterrows():
    
    for index2, row2 in table_2.iterrows():

        column_c = False
        column_d = False

        if len(row2['Column C']) > 0:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(row['Column B'], '*' + row2['Column C'] + '*'):
                column_c = True

        if len(row2['Column D']) > 0:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(row['Column B'], '*' + row2['Column D'] + '*'):
                column_d = True

        if column_c:
            table_2.at[index2, 'Column E'] = table_2.at[index2, 'Column E'] + row['Column A'] + ', '

        if column_c & column_d:
            table_2.at[index2, 'Column F'] = table_2.at[index2, 'Column F'] + row['Column A'] + ', '

print(table_2)
```

Table2 as output should look like this

| Column C | Column D | Column D | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | cats | 1, 2, 3, | 2, 3, |
| me | dogs | 4, |  |

My code delivers the results but it takes a long time because my Table1 has over 35000 rows and Table2 over 5000 rows. I read that it is not advised to use loops on dataframe.  I was wondering what would be the more efficient ways to do this? Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a real input for table_1 and the matching expected output? Your current code only fills empty strings

Comment: Sorry. I just edited my code and tested it.